# Sculpting Symetry X Issue

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I have started sculpting in Blender and Im not the biggest expert. I have a little issue now. When I started sculping Symetry X was on and it is still on. It worked all perfectly, it did mirror each side as it should. But now I started working on hands and as you can see in the pictures on one hand its fine but on the other hand at the finger tips there is "extra mass" and I do not know where it comes from. I did not turn off X Symetry or anything. I was just normally working. X Symetry still works at all but the fingers are an issue for that, and I do not know why. Please help me! Thx!

1[image: ]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze1V9.jpg

[2[image: ]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze1V9.jpg

[3[image: ]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/643Xk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this, go into edit mode (where you can manipulate verts manually), you can try pressing tab to jump over. Tap 'A' should select all verts, then go to the Mesh menu, select symmetrize. Go back to sculpt mode, I think this should fix your issue.